# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load hangs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-xi

During debug, when I reach the method `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(InfoObject, EnterpriseSession)`, the debuging simply stops.

I mean i does't pass it, just keep on this method forever, no errors, no nothing. My page just shows "waiting for localhost" and that's it.

I'm using visualstudio 2010 connecting to a Business Objects XI 3.1 instance

EDIT:

I see now that there is a timeout error timeout was configured for 10 minutes):

```
objReportDocument.Load(objInfoObject, enterpriseSession);
```

Error:

```
Request timed out because there has been no reply from the server in 600000 ms.
```

Comment: Have you turned on all Debugging errors in Visual Studio?  Having used CR in the past, I don't envy your road.

Comment: hi, I got a timeout error. 
thanks for ur reply, CR is a really a pain

Comment: Don't know if CR XI 3.1 can do this, but have you tried to create a custom object that feeds the report itself?  For example, Telerik Reporting engine let's you work off a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried all suggested remedies like setting no default printer, clearing print spooler but
all did not help.

Since the .NET web app was done in 2008, I changed the application pool on IIS from `DefaultAppPool` to `Classic.NET` pool;
it worked!